# How do I change "-" to blank in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula `A1-B1` which is giving me `-` in the cells where `A1 and B1 is both 0.00`. This is affecting my std dev formula. If I replace this with `#N/A`, it still does not solve the issue.

How do I replace `-` to `blank cells` via a formula in Excel?

When I copy and paste special (values) `-` to another cell it gives me `0`.

Comment: Please check number formatting - I assume it looks sth like 0;0;-;@ which means that a zero is shown as a - (dash) --> 3rd section within number formatting.

Comment: What about `=IF(A1-B1=0,"",A1-B1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to just use Find and Replace in Excel. `CTRL+H` and type "-" in `Find What`and `Replace All` with an empty field.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SUBSTITUTE(CELL_WITH_MINUS_SIGN,"-","")